# controller class mapping in spring mvc

Tags: xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound

I was not able to find the error in the following code as i am just learning spring mvc.
Not able to map the request in the controller class and tried to check the configuration files but was not able to find the error. kindly help me with the program.

web.xml

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

 <web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>   
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 
  </servlet-class>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

telusko-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd ">
  <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
  <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.telusko"></ctx:component-scan>
  </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
<artifactId>teludkospringmvc</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>teludkospringmvc Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.8.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.36</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency> 

 </dependencies>
 <build>
 <finalName>teludkospringmvc</finalName>
 </build>
 </project>
```

Controller class

```
package com.telusko;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
@Controller
public class AddController {

@RequestMapping("/add")
public void add(){
System.out.print("hi");
}

}
```

ErrorResult

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/teludkospringmvc/add] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'telusko'
```

Comment: did you try just localhost:8080/add?

Comment: No, as soon as i click the submit button in index.jsp where action="add"  it should map with the controller. Thank you for the suggestion will check.please check the configuration files if anything wrong.

Comment: if you code is in github, i can take a look for you

Comment: Yes sure thank you i will place in git hub

Comment: @Chi Dov .The project source code uploaded on github. please have a look and let me know how can i solve the issue. https://github.com/logicMark/Springmvc-Mapping-of-controller

Comment: problem solved, please see my answer

Comment: @Chi Dov Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this line in your `telusko-servlet.xml` file to enable the spring MVC annotations:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: after adding `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` follow mlg's suggestion.

You still miss internal reourse view resolver which they can't find you display.jsp

telusko-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

AddController.java

```
@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(){
        return "display";
    }

}
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s anything to do with resource resolver. The error is when spring fails to bind the controllers. As rightly pointed out by @mlg its the missing mvc config annotation driven.

Comment: he followed mlg's code add this line <mvc:annotation-driven/>, but he still missing resource resolver, i run his code already in github.

Comment: Okay in that case the question is closed in my opinion as misconfigured view resolver would give him different error message.